# Create a new start in middle of loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have to create a new 2D array from these 2 arrays:

> CViEbee[][]
>
> ```
> 1 2   3   4   1   2
>
> 2 1   3   2   4   1
> ```
>
> Hdeg[]
>
> ```
> 1 9   9   9   9   1
> ```

The new array (`QST`) uses `CViEbee` elements that consist in numbers from 1 to 6 (if exist), and then use them to access index in `Hdeg`. It will look like this:

> QST[][]
>
> ```
> 10    10  9   9   0   0
>
> 10    10  9   9   0   0
> ```

```
 QST[0][0] = 10 because, CViEbee[0][j]=1 if j=0 and j=4 then 
    QST[0][0] = Hdeg[0]+Hdeg[4] = 1+9 = 10
    QST[0][5] = 0 because, CViEbee[0][j]=6 --> no CViEbee element = 6

    QST[1][3] = 9 because, CViEbee[1][j] = 4 if j= 4 then

    QST[1][3] = Hdeg[4]= 9
```

I've tried to write the program but it's still wrong. This is the code:

```
int y;
double x = 0; //(Hdeg and QST is double)
int i,j,k,l;

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    y = 1;
    for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        if (CViEbee[i][j] == y) x = x + Hdeg[j];
        k = 0;
        if(j == 6) {
            QST[i][k] = x;
            System.out.print(QST[i][k]);
        }
    }
    j = 0;
    y++;
    x = 0;
}

System.out.println();
```

Can somebody help me, please :)

Answer (score 1):

Some flaw/problems

1. the first inner *if* statement doesn't have a block (`{` and `}` probably missing)
2. the condition of the second inner `if` statement will never be `true`, `j` can't be 6 at this point
3. the assignment `j=0` near the end is not necessary
4. you don't need `y` because it is always equal to `i+1`

---

Here is a working solution. Please note, that I changed the names of the array slightly, but you should be able to grab the idea and use it in your code:

```
int[][] cv = new int[][]{{1,2,3,4,1,2},{2,1,3,2,4,1}};
int[] hd = new int[]{1,9,9,9,9,1};
int[][] q = new int[2][6];

for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
  for (int x = 1; x <= 6; x++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < 6; col++) {
      if (cv[row][col] == x) {
        q[row][x-1] += hd[col];
      }
    }
  }
}

for (int[] row:q) {
  for (int col:row) {
    System.out.print(col + "\t");
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Not the most efficient solution (requires three nested loops) but at least a starting point ;)

(BTW: [you can test it here in ideone](http://ideone.com/ZgbYL))

Comment: I use y for find the number I want in CViEbee (1 to 6) so after find how many 1 in CViEbee it increase to 2 and so on..

Comment: @Henni also don't declare loop variables ouside the loop for(int i=0;...) it will help you avoid problems that may not be that obvious